# How to close the window in egui

Tags: rust, egui

Well, strange question, I'm using `egui` and `macroquad`, showing `LogsWindow` over `CentralWindow`. But I just can't close it using click on the cross (`.open()` method for `Window` object).

```rust
pub struct LogsWindow<'a> {
    pub is_opened: &'a mut bool,
    pub logs: Logs,
}

impl<'a> LogsWindow<'a> {
    pub fn new(logs: Logs, is_opened: &'a mut bool) -> Self {
        Self { is_opened, logs }
    }
    pub fn name(&self) -> &'static str {
        "Logs"
    }
    pub fn show(&mut self, ctx: &egui::Context) {
        egui::Window::new(self.name())
            .open(self.is_opened)
            .show(ctx, |_| {});
    }
    pub fn ui(&mut self, ui: &mut Ui) {
        egui::Grid::new("logs_grid").striped(true).show(ui, |ui| {
            ------smth-----
        });
    }
}
```

And for  UI:

```rust
egui_macroquad::ui(|egui_ctx| {
        LogsWindow::new(logs.clone(), &mut true).show(egui_ctx);

        egui::CentralPanel::default()
            .frame(Frame::none().fill(Color32::TRANSPARENT))
            .show(egui_ctx, |central_panel_ui| {
                ------------smth more-----------------
            });
    });

    egui_macroquad::draw();
```

I understand that `egui` is in immediate mode UI and therefore draws each frame creating new LogsWindow with .open(true), but I don't know how to actually make it work

Comment: You have to store LogsWindow in the app state instead of creating it on each frame.